# Sitecore users are present in core db - [aspnet_Users] table, but not shown in User Manager wizard

Tags: user-management

We migrated our Sitecore 8.2 initial release to Sitecore 9.2.

In sitecore 8.2 initial release we had sitecore users synched with AD(using LDAP )

Since Sitecore 9.2 will not support AD, we removed all the configuration of LDAP.

When we login to **core db -- [aspnet_Users] table, we are able to see our users(about 150 users)**

But these users are not showing in the User Manager wizard.

Comment: Hi @PVM what was your migration process from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.2? Did you apply core db migration scripts

Comment: Hi @JuliusA, yes we applied the core db migration scripts before 9.2 upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your upgrade process, either way it seems your `aspnet_Users` table doesn't have matching records in `aspnet_Membership` table. This is where issue lies.

To verify use the SQL Query below

```
select U.* from aspnet_Users as U
JOIN aspnet_Membership as M on U.UserId = M.UserId
```

The resulting users above should appear in the User Manager screen.

Please note in Sitecore 9.x there is default implementation in Identity Server to ensure usernames are unique, as we can use federated authentication. Worth validating if the usernames after your upgrade are unique. I have [blogged about this previously and worth having a read.](https://360agileweb.wordpress.com/2020/02/28/sitecore-host-part-three/)

Comment: yes the user detail are not there in the aspnet_Membership table. Is there a way to insert the user detail only in the aspnet_Membership table

Comment: Yes, you can script I believe. However, worth checking why they were not migrated in the first place. If you insert new entries, it may mean users have to reset their passwords for example